# Visual Studio 2015 XAML Designer crashes with WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Has anyone came up with a work around for these crashes?

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.MockGenericType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.MockGenericType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineNestedTypes(MockTypeDefinition mockType, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineProperty(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineProperty(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineProperty(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineParameters(ParameterInfo[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineMethod(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, MethodInfo method)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineInterfaces(MockTypeDefinition mockType, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineField(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, FieldInfo fieldInfo, DependencyPropertyContext dependencyPropertyContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.MockType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.InitializeMockType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.get_RuntimeType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.Metadata.TypeHelper.GetMemberAccess(IType type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectXmlnsDefinitionMap.XmlNamespaceTypeMap.IsVisibleType(IType type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectXmlnsDefinitionMap.XmlNamespaceTypeMap.GetType(String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectXmlnsDefinitionMap.GetType(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.SampleDataAwareNamespaceTypeResolver.GetType(IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.ResolveTypeInternal(ITypeResolver typeResolver, IXmlNamespaceTypeResolver xmlNamespaceTypeResolver, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.ResolveType(ITypeResolver typeResolver, IXmlNamespaceTypeResolver xmlNamespaceTypeResolver, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetTypeId(ITypeResolver typeResolver, DocumentXmlnsDefinitionMap documentNamespaces, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean instantiateUnrecognizedTypes, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetTypeId(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeName, Boolean inMarkupExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseRootElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.Parse(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlDocumentReference xmlDocumentReference, XmlDocument xmlDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseInternal(XamlParserContext parserContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlLanguageService.ParseDocument(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.SceneMarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, IUndoService undoService, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateMarkupDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, IHostTextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean cloneBufferToStandalone, Boolean suppressUI, SceneDocument originalSceneDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OpenDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass27_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

I reload then it just crashes again.

Comment: What XAML are you using to make that happen?

Comment: This is definitely a bug and should be reported to MS.

Comment: Happens on an empty window. Also when changing the code the xaml, I get an exception saying "this key has already been added". I keep sending frowns, how can I talk to visual studio directly?

Comment: Same for me, I've already reported to VS group.

Comment: I can confirm the same bug in VS2015 comminity edition.
Looks like the "Properties" window causes that crush. When "Properties" window is open the bug occur, while when it's closed everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing this exception (MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator) and have the target platform set to X64 or ARM, try switching to X86 and rebuilding.

Since we can't run project code in X64 or ARM, we attempt to provide a set of mock types based on your code. We are adding additional warnings in future updates of Visual Studio.

Comment: I'd be nice if it would mock my types in x64 so I could use the designer and property window. Some of my projects are x64 and its a pain to have to switch my config every time I want to build.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. I've found if I change the project output to x86 instead of x64 it works. (after you rebuild that is)

Not really a good solution, definitely needs to be looked at.

My dump:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.TypeDefinition..ctor(TypeDefinitionContext context, Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockDefinition..ctor(TypeDefinitionContext context, Type sourceType, Type mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.TypeDefinitionContext.DefineNestedType(Type type, TypeDefinition declaringType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineField(TypeDefinition typeDefinition, FieldInfo fieldInfo, DependencyPropertyContext dependencyPropertyContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineBaseType(Type baseType, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.PopulateMockType(Type type, MockTypeDefinition mockType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.DefineType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockTypes.MockTypeGenerator.MockType(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.InitializeMockType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.MockType.get_RuntimeType()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.InitializeClass()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.get_PropertyIndex()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.CreateLocalProperty(String propertyName, MemberKey& key)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.CreateMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberKey& key)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.TryGetCachedMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, Boolean create, IMember& member)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MemberCollection.GetMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberAccessTypes access)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.ProjectContextType.GetMember(MemberType memberTypes, String memberName, MemberAccessTypes access)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetPropertyKey(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String typeAndPropertyName, XmlNamespace targetTypeNamespace, IType targetTypeId, MemberType memberTypes, MemberType defaultType, Boolean allowProtectedPropertiesOnTargetType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlTypeHelper.GetPropertyKey(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlElementReference, String fullPropertyName, XmlNamespace targetTypeNamespace, IType targetTypeId, MemberType memberTypes, MemberType defaultType, Boolean allowProtectedPropertiesOnTargetType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser.CreateNodeFromTextValue(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlNamespaceResolver, TypeConverter typeConverter, ITypeId valueTypeId, String value, XmlAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser.GetPropertyValue(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IXmlNamespaceResolver xmlNamespaceResolver, TypeConverter typeConverter, IType valueTypeId, String value, Boolean removeEscapeCharacters, XmlAttribute attribute)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.SetProperty(XamlParserContext parserContext, ITextLocation lineInformation, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlAttribute attribute, IProperty propertyKey)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertyAndValue(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IPropertyValueTypeMetadata metadata, IType propertyTargetType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseStyleOrTemplate(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, ITypeId type, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, DocumentNode& node)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, IProperty childProperty, TypeConverter textTypeConverter, ITypeId textType, PropertyHandling propertyHandling)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement, Predicate`1 propertyFilter)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.AddPropertiesAndChildren(XamlParserContext parserContext, DocumentCompositeNodeReference nodeReference, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseCompositeElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseElementContent(XamlParserContext parserContext, IDocumentNodeReference nodeReference, IType typeId, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseRootElement(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlElementReference xmlElementReference, XmlElement xmlElement)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.Parse(XamlParserContext parserContext, XmlDocumentReference xmlDocumentReference, XmlDocument xmlDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlParser.ParseInternal(XamlParserContext parserContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.XamlLanguageService.ParseDocument(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Markup.MarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.SceneMarkupDocument..ctor(IDocumentContext documentContext, IUndoService undoService, ITypeId expectedRootType, ITextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding documentEncoding, IMarkupLanguageService languageService, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateMarkupDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, IHostTextBuffer textBuffer, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean cloneBufferToStandalone, Boolean suppressUI, SceneDocument originalSceneDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OpenDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean isReadOnly, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextBase.OpenProjectDocument(ISourceItemContext sourceItem, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextBase.OpenDocument(String path, Boolean suppressUI)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.ResourceDictionaryContentProvider.set_ProjectDocument(IProjectDocument value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.ResourceManager.GetContentProviderForResourceDictionary(IProjectDocument projectDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.DocumentResourceContainer..ctor(ResourceManager manager, IProjectDocument document)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.ResourceManager.AddDocument(IProjectDocument projectDocument)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.ResourceManager.SetTargetProjectContexts(IProjectContext[] newProjectContexts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.UI.ResourcePane.ResourceManager.DocumentViewContext_ViewOpened(Object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OnViewOpened(ViewEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.OpenViewWorker(SceneView sceneView, Boolean ensureHostOpen)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DocumentViewContext.CreateAndOpenViewInternal(SceneDocument document, CancellationToken cancelToken, Boolean activate, Boolean ensureOpenInHost)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass27_0`1.<MarshalOut>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```